# Is the class loading different between standard JVM and Android Dalvik

Tags: java, android, jvm, factory-pattern, dalvik

the question might be a bit vague because i'm not sure how to put the scenario into context.

I'm trying to implement a *factory pattern* for object creation on my current Java program, which is a standalone app. I tried to use the *self-registering* way of creating the object list in the factory, as detailed in [here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

I encountered an error along the way though, that the `static` block in the object was never executed, and the list remained empty. I did a bit of research and found that the `static` block will only be executed one time, during the time when the class is loaded by the JVM.

That wonders me though, because i'd used the same method on a Android application before, and it worked without an issue. The `static` block will just execute to register the object itself to the factory.

Is there a difference between these 2 VM that is causing this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with class *loading*. The factory pattern is about class *instantiation*. The static block is executed the first time the class is referenced (because you called a static method, accessed a static field, instantiated the class, used reflection on it, ...). Dalvik's behavior should be interoperable with the JVM. What error are you encountering?

Comment: There were no error while implementing this on Android. However when i try to do this in a standalone JVM program, the `Map` of objects in the `Factory` class will always be empty, and resulted in `NullPointerException` when the object creation is taking place. On Android the objects are added into the `Map` with no other extra codes

Comment: You may want to ask this differently: reduce the code to a minimal functional example that behaves differently on Dalvik and Java, and ask "what should the behavior be?"  It's possible the behavior is undefined and simply happens to work differently.

Comment: just guessing, but maybe dalvik eagerly loads all classes. openjdk's standard class loaders only do so when a class is needed. it would be possible to write a custom classloader that pre-touches all classes in a jar.

Comment: Yes indeed that's my guess as well, just that i can't find any documents to support that, hence the question here. I don't know how to structure the question so it's a bit vague...

Comment: Class initialization does not occur as a consequence of class loading. Nothing in Dalvik attempts to initialize classes without cause.